# Apache virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a number of virtual hosts in my apache installation. I have two IP adresses that I use, one for SSL only.

My default virtual host is like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Problem is that I have another vhost that looks likt this and should match SSL on the other IP only:

```
<VirtualHost 94.75.193.86:443>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to http://host:443 I get the default virtual host instead of the SSL virtual host. I guess this is because I use "NameVirtualHost *" instead of specifying a port.

What I am puzzled about is that when I change the default NameVirtualHost to *:80 every other virtualhost (non-ssl) stops working and every request is sent to the default vhost.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at your `ssl.conf` (or equivalent) file.

When you do a `/usr/sbin/apachctl graceful` after making your config changes, I bet it says something to the efect that your VirtualHost is conflicting with the default SSL handler.

Comment: Got lots of these:
[Sun Oct 25 13:36:46 2009] [error] VirtualHost *:80 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results

Comment: ahh. Right - you can have one *or* the other, not both.  I hadn't seen that first time through your config.